Do Hindu scriptures give a way to assimilate or classify knowledge gained from non-Hindu / foreign sources?
The specific issue in mind is assimilation of modern era scientific knowledge within Hindu knowledge structure. But the scope of this question is broader, and any kind of non-Hindu knowledge which can be dealt within Hindu fold is well within the scope.
Anything that sheds light on the subject with a proper scriptural basis is welcome, including scriptures that prohibit such additions.

Unclear what you are asking; scientific knowledge is knowledge of the workings of the sensual universe, Hindu knowledge is knowledge of Brahman, of the spiritual realm. Scripture deals with Brahman, not the rules for the workings of the physical realm.

Science is also the knowledge genes, and Gita also talks of Varnāshankar. There is an undeniable overlap in scope of science and dharmā, even if there none in the knowledge. For centuries, Europeans have made attempts to assimilate Hindu knowledge into what is their academic knowledge today. This is how they know about zero. If Hindus want to start assimilating European knowledge, does Hinduism have any legitimate way to do that? That's what I am asking.
